# SMS with image in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to send SMS with image on Xamarin.Forms application.

I've tried using Xamarin.Essentials or Messaging from Xamarin.Plugins, but only text SMS is supported.

How to do?

Comment: SMS does not support multimedia content, use MMS instead.

Comment: Thank you for your comment and editie.
How to sned mms in Xamarin.Forms?

Comment: I don't think that any library for Xamarin Forms supports MMS. You can implement by yourself using native libraries for each platform, or use an http server for that. The Google Firebase platform is usually a quick start.

Comment: ok,I see what you mean.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can convert the image to base64 string which you will be able to send using SMS since it will be represented as a text.

It will cost a lot though since SMS support only 160 characters and you can see an example on this website on how to covert an image to string and how much space it will take depending on the size of the image.

[Click on the Sample Button](https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter#)

The preferred way to my knowledge is to use http post to a server after converting the image to base64 string as JSON. Than, convert it back to image and store it there in the server or do whatever you want to it.

Example of JSON Request:

```
{
    "message" : "This is a text message",
    "Image" : "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAANIAAAAzCAYAAADigVZlAAAQN0lEQVR4nO2dCXQTxxnHl0LT5jVteHlN+5q+JCKBJITLmHIfKzBHHCCYBAiEw+I2GIMhDQ0kqQolIRc1SV5e+prmqX3JawgQDL64bK8x2Ajb2Bg7NuBjjSXftmRZhyXZ1nZG1eL1eGa1kg2iyua9X2TvzvHNN/Ofb2Z2ZSiO4ygZGZm+EXADZGSCgYAbICMTDATcABmZYCDgBsjIBAMBN0BGJhgIuAEyMsGA1wQdHZ1UV1cX5XK5qM7OzgcMRuNTrSbTEraq6strhdfzruTk5Wpz8q5c1l7Jyb6szc3K1l7RggtFxcWX2dvVB02mtmVOp3NIV2fnQFie2WyB5QS84TIy/YnXBFBI8BMM/pDqat0XzIVM08lTSVxyytn6jAuZV4FuzmtzclJz8/LT8vML0nJzr54HYkpLS88oTkxMMZ48mchlXrxUX1ffcBCUM8xms8lCkgk6pCT6aZvZvCrzYpbu2PfxHAg8l+obGmOt1vaJQBAPkvI5nM5fWyyWWTU1tfuA+IqOHDvGgehVCK4pA91oGZn+xluCAc0thtj4hCT72XOp9S0thi2FBQWPvb13z9RN61QH5s8NYxbMDct7KXyudt7MGeeWLFrwn8iVKz7auDZy3Z7dbzz91p43B8ZsjYLlDKmprd3/ffwpLjWNqbW32xcFuuEyMv2J2M1BJpMpKiExxZKZeamira1tvvqdt8OWL1l8asq4kNbRzz7NTRo7uuMPo4Y7Rz/zFBc64lluzHNDuZFDFe5PICx25/aY2B3bogf/dd9fKCA+CuytohOSkjuyLmtLXRwXGujGy8j0F8Qbdrt9bDpzQQ8jSHl5+dLt0VsOThgzwj7i6Se5kOHDuIljR9mXRrykjZj/wlVeSONHP8+FhykrJoeOsY8aNoQLAYJa9erShIPvvRsKhQTK/YleX3Pw5KlErpKt+iLQjZeR6S9IN35VXl75r3gw4HU6/Z6ojes/gMKAUQiKBQKiUvvLC1/MXL18WcKsaZOrJ4WObly7euUJsOQ7FjZ9Sh2IVC4oLhihZk6d1LB5/dpt+9R/hnuq4Xl5VwvT0jLKXS7XOHgaCAm0I2Rk+gL2os1mewXsiUw5uXlZn8T9LVI5ZWI1jEQTxozkgECgkDrmKqfrFy8ILwJ7om+3bNoQumTRwtDoqE0fTBsf2ggwg+jVBdOCT7eYwGfnti2bQXA6ME2nr9mbnHLOWV/fEI3WTdO0jMzdZjBAKWBwX8ojCqm8vOJoYvLp9qPfHTmy5rXlJ+BSbtzI5+5EI4ALRCTHHHpaQ8zWqOidO2IooBAKRKRDQDwGevJ4w8SQUR0e0bmB0QxEKh2IYsdbTW0zmIxM4/Wi4q9BfQMkCikCoAEUADgEeI3xOOVedkicp14e1V2uLwSpTwxNAPwRaGC7OQFqQp9xGDT+1ksUUubFrMoLFy/VL5g7+4ep48fa+P0Pz9jnn4H7JCcQBbP79V1rgJDmASE9um7NqvmxMdFbVateiwd7KKswHx+dwBKwzGq1jgDRrjQ7W5sB6hvsRUhQQCyh8Sg4xwW64/oTpUQ/CIm7xz652yg9flb40R+xIn5i/LWJKKSk5NOuwqIi7cSQkXooAD6ywE8YneDyLWrDuq/WR67+BvxcB5dtG9dGHgF7oZsgSuWFz555c0LISKcwIvHlAHSdnR0P37h5699pzIW6NrNlptFoIglJ7cOAgcTf40711nH3g5AguEH3/4YGaZPSj/6Ix/hGmKd/hXQqIanz5q1b8WA5VwOXdLwgoIjAsk2/Y1v0odUrXj0OT+vgNSCkjgXzZleANF3wpI6PRALxcDDt7BlTby+NWPgdqOPBisrKz8E+zFFXX79Sp9fjhKQiDAqjx6kRHmfCdHDWZek+zCp+gnac6i7XhxOSUkAExiZI7D32y73wtbKfy/CnPDdEISUkJjsrKiqPhocp86ZPGGeDSzkIWJa1Rq5ccXyDas1X8PBBuG9Cow8UE/yEaYYPeZybPnFcM1gGRh/6+KNhNbV1o7Mua29dysrOdblcQ4SvDHmMg5s/I2ZAxNP+bQz5zaVaABz0ij7kh6D7NVJnwL1NLJLXn47DCQmXjkXSqAnpFB4/CO2KkODjEE861B9i7VcKwPldgaQJQfKi4yFWkNZbPXzZuP4iQRobaLrBIhEpubP0xq2E9989MHnLpg3rX5hFlz3/1BMcWLaVRm/eeIieNL4KRhi450EjDxQOvAf2T+mrli9bDZaAq3Zu37b3nbf2zvnwg/d/DoRENbcYRmhzcn84n5peDkQ0FbNHUmMGjD/LtsGesnCi5GEEnYbLH+clP9ox6ABiRdKzmDz9ISR0wKgx7WJE7ILtxUUxlQQfGDFtQutC7cH1OUPIi8NbPWjZUtBgbIzApFMQhZSccrbrav61zAqWfWR79JbJ8+eG5Q97/HccfB0I/P4eEJADRigoJP6NBvgzBC715s2coTuwf9+0qI3rKbB3ooCQKCAkCgiJgkKCS7uWFuMbiUkpjpzcvCvg9yGIkFicwZiGeRMR7oQPB+x8VEy+5OcRDiDcoCdBErI/QsINdmH5pGiPAxUT6cQLxYjkY5D7aozdaiQNQ8iLoz+EhPY1i7FRg7ORKKTUtHSdVptTarPZhr737oFHgRj+7lmeVcRsjfrwxdkzc+DSDj50VU6Z0LR5/drDK5a8HLt4QfhusAfaBUQz8tDHHw/atE5FEhLkods6/ZfHjsdzZWXlJwRCGoxppAbTKG+gjeadoyZ0Duo43MbU6LmuJpTPCwk3WGFHqTyg9xiJbcIJSS2AtJkWG9R89Imgew8mI91zmcfQPfeo/D21iC9wdUZg2oaWoaG7xYvm59vFQ6qHt0EloQycb4WTN25cuttBFBKIRpfAsstkNpvD4Xtye9/802PLFi/6J1y6LXpx3mUQleJARHKCaGRbvWLZO1AwQEgUEBIFhOQWDRAS5UVIFOfinrheVHw2MTmFEwgJ1yAVxvFiKDBlaJA0uJmbrycEcw+3P0PTCDtOeJ1F8uKWCFL2fr5EOZzNOL+g0Qq9Lxz0IQQ7ceUKhSR2jzRxqb2Uj/MP46Ueb2WwyH1hREaPzln+HlFIjY1N+1NSzlirq/Wfg99/9saunVRszLaHdu3YHg32PueAOP4Klm8lk0JHt4GfZ6yPXE0tf2WxZCHZ7Q7K4XC667I77IuZC5nehIRzvBhqJD86s/KgM7CG7p4FUafh8pPsRAeFhu69SfWnjTgBisEi5aKDoQBjl7f9FSqgWBq/FPdVSIxIvTh/+Sok3OSI5kf7XbgvR/1yR2REIXV0dIRmX9beys7WljsdzhEeIQFBxFDLXl5E7doRMzFs+pTG+XNmFX726acPHo6Loz45fJhasmihG29CstraqfZ2+wCXyzWCZau+T0w63d9CQgcy6aACdRxDcJqKkJ9kp9Q9iK9tVGPyqQXgDkbg7wqCX6SgRmyAdmpo7w/JAyEk1Calj2WgYjOKXL8zsRKFBKNQA4hKp8+c62poaPwjfI0HLOfcX4WAYoqO2jQKLPVSdr++azsUkK9CagdCstnah14rvJ767XdHHSUlN64IhISbOdDO9IZYp4gNTIbGd7wCk1ch0jHodf4VJjGkHDig9nKYNLCDWSQN/3YD6hdWgl38JOLtpA9FTEg4f6JlqwX3pAoJTRMiUgZDKAP1HcyHTrgaYR4xIVFOp/PJgmuFFfngf52dnU+Q0nkDLuOsVitlb293Cwhib7dTFotlWloaU3s1vyANpHsUObVDHcISGt1XIWkIzpXSabhlli8zsD+oJdpGirRS/YIDd4LJeurCTX68WKQsqXA+E9qG+ho9FSSVIbwnVUgajB1olO8xEYgKCdLaaoouKv6hrNXYOt9ut8PlGAF3hMGWAa83NjVRNpDG4XDcwWg0rklLZ7iS0hufgXQDESHhliBCx3oDdUYBIR1LqAOtGxct0DqEHYd7eHg3hMRKbD9D8KvUZ3MqTFuFbVKI+AIdwDh/4soXTj5ouxkabyfJBl+E5G0f2isfUUjwD5RAzGbzQzW1dXOqdbphNbW1VE0NHp1OD6KOTVRI7UCIgusP6Gtq9iWnnOmqul0dhXkgi3M+BM5+pNOtELp7pvDWMRDcC4x8B6OzLzrgcLOssOPQAcuK2N0XIfXqVI9tqJB5+8Xa7Eu96IuwuP4Suyf0J85ejhYX0t2MSBTBHh4Vmp4opJYWgxujsZWqr2+ggJAoXY2eAoO/F/Ce1YYXkVBIMKKB5SJc0sGl3rC8/ALt2fNpzQ6HM9zVW0i4WVXoRP5ZjprufrbB0d0RBfccx0h3v8aCK1voWLTjOE+d/GsxJEeLzbAFdPdRMv/KUSwtfX+Es4ulex42kHzGd74Cc8/ouc8LXen5PV6QD62XEaRXENrrbVI00uIPvMWExHl8F0/37DeSDb4KieRHFpeeKCSDwegGCqmurt4tFn9E1CMigaWd52/jQX5fUlqakprOmMB/LzU3N+OEJNYgKc735agYfbPBl6f/pI5jfMgnNVr5UiYPuqxV+5CXFz4uAguFgFuKS53hSQj7UuzrD3x09LYXQ9vN0GQ/k8aOGpe+T0K6XV1NWaxWKYcNA1sMhgdANHLvgzo7u9zXK1n20PnzaVYQ8ZbB5SFBSPzszkp0vgLjEG+dyNL4iEBacvBovHQcFIeU42ZWpEP7KiTSS75qifmF/sS1lwc30H3pB1xkEgpJIZKfj5q4yOevkEjix054fgsJfu0BwkcZEqCs3zQ2Ne8pLin5urpad8hkaltQUnLjGbDfimQyLhjg298gDe7tb9Isoabx3wRV0/jXTvgBrfKkE+aLE8kjzCtcQvD5FB7UCLgyQgh288tTJSEfaVJB68QRQXt/N1GBaRuPmsY/OyP5UYov+DTCvBq65/JRCGq/AlM3tF+4xBSzQYncw7VPCOlhff8ICQqotq7OfRghWKphMZstaxKTUywnTp5qPHP2vOn0mXNcKpNhPpWYxKWmpjeDZd0WtG4vjZORuRcoafEI2QO/hASXdAajUcozpEGF14uPpgPhWK22xRaLdUbV7eo3b9ws28+yVXsdDvtceHonC0nmPoShey89ien9jkjNLQaqrc1MxASw2donpaZn1JeVlyeBfdEv2232O/sjMe4DJ8r8+GDo7i8K4va1KrH8PgsJPkuC+yL4tgL8JAGPucvKK2MzM7PaWltbl4AyB/wvj10Wksz9CCeCaDSC+CQkGInq6utF90Q8oIzf5l0tuFheXvkPsI962HN6JwtJ5n6FofEiwn3hsxeShVQF9kVQRPDfSZKwN6Kampt3Xiu83mQymcL5a/BrE1BMspBk7kNUdO8TVeGJoCiShOR+DaiuTvKfFQbpHqmoqMzW6/WJ8PgbOQ6XkQlKsBd5IUFaDAbJkQhitdpWgKUg226zLYS/y0KS+TGAvdjc3OKmqamFamtroywWq+gpHY/ZbBnU3GL4FHx+A8r5BeEhrYxM0BFwA2RkgoGAGyAjEwwE3AAZmWAg4AbIyAQDATdARiYYCLgBMjLBQMANkJEJBgJugIxMMPBfChd6NRZ5pkMAAAAASUVORK5CYII="
}
```

You will need to learn more about the http request headers and security, but once you learn how to use it, it will open many possibilities to you.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I try it!

Comment: I tryed it, But the letters are still going.
I want to go to MMS Like an attachment

Comment: can you please explain your scenario? If you use http and send the data as JSON, you will send the message as one property and the image as another JSON property. MMS require sim cards and phone numbers while http request are free using the internet. 
I will edit my answer and add an example of JSON Request.

Comment: If I send json to http, what is web address and port number?

Comment: port is the default for all internet connections which is 80 
the web address is where you will host your solution. You have multiple options depending on which platform you want to host the backend on. You can develop an asp.net Web API or using .NET core. You can also use php as a backend. I used Slim Framework and was able to create a simple and powerful api. PHP works in almost all environments so does .NET core. ASP.NET web api works only on Windows Servers

Comment: You can test locally ofcourse. You don't need to subscribe to any hosting plans while developing. But , you will need to open a port on your pc and allow traffic to it. also, the devices must be in the same network

Comment: You didn't explain your scenario though

Comment: Do you do that when you send mms from a normal smartphone?

Comment: I want to make an app that will go through text messages if I hang up while using my smartphone.I want to send an image to the messages. I will make the app xamarin.form.

Comment: Although sending SMS to the app was successful, but I do not know how to send MMS.

Comment: Please create a different question since the scenario is different than the original question and this almost become a chat.

Comment: There seems to be no more way. Thank you for your help.